# Qat Equation Solver

Tags: code-golf

[Qat](https://www.quinapalus.com/qat.html) is a tool that lets you search for words matching a given pattern, often used by crossword and other word puzzle writers and solvers.

In this challenge, you will have to implement a specific part of Qat, namely a subset of the "equation solver".

### Equations

The output of a Qat query depends on the dictionary you use (i.e. the list of words you are pattern matching against) and the pattern you input.

The most basic thing you can do in Qat is define **simple patterns**, which are sequences of symbols which should match some words (similar to regular expressions). In this problem, we will only include two different types of symbols:

- A *lowercase* letter, which just matches that letter
- A period `.`, which can match any letter (equivalent to the regular expression `[a-z]`).

For example, using the base Qat dictionary, the simple pattern `l.......v` matches `leitmotiv` and `lermontov`, so the output is `leitmotiv lermontov`.

(There are many more complicated patterns you can also define, but we'll ignore them for this challenge.)

In Qat, you can also describe **equations**. From the website (description simplified and modified to only use our simple patterns):

> Qat's equation solver is based around *variables*, represented by capital letters from A to Z.
>
> An equation consists of a left-hand side (LHS) followed by an equals sign `=` and a right-hand side (RHS).
>
> The LHS consists of a sequence of variables and simple patterns.
> The RHS is a simple pattern, which matches any word that fits that pattern [which is then output as a result].
>
> **Qat will try to assign strings of characters to the variables so that the whole LHS matches the RHS.**

Multiple equations are separated by semicolons, in which case all of the equations must be satisfied, the solution to each of the equations is shown in sequence. If there are multiple valid solutions, each of them is output in sequence.

#### Examples

It's probably easiest to understand with some examples.

Suppose we are using the dictionary `[one two onetwo onesix]`. Then:

- The pattern `A=o..` is an equation which says "`A` must match a three letter word starting with 'o'"; the only option here is `one`, so the output is `one`.
- The pattern `A=o..;A=..e` is an equation which says "`A` must match a three letter word starting with 'o' and also a three letter word ending with 'e'"; the only option here is `one`, so the output is `one one` (because there are two equations).
- The pattern `A=...` says "`A` must match a three letter word"; there are two options here (`one` and `two`), so the output is `one; two`.
- The pattern `A=oneB;B=...` says "`A` must `one` prepended to `B`, where `B` is a three-letter word"; the only option here is that `B` is `two`, making  `A` equal to `onetwo`. Thus, the output is `onetwo two`. (Note the solutions to the equations are output in order.)
- The pattern `o..A=ones..` says "look for a sequence of characters `A` where the pattern `o..A` can match `ones...`". The only option in this case is that `A` equals `six`, in which case we find a word in the dictionary which matches both `o..six` and `ones..`; the only solution here is `onesix`, so this produces the output `onesix`.
- The pattern `A=...;B=...;C=AB` says "`C` must be the combination of two three-letter words"; the output is thus `one two onetwo`.

### Challenge

Given a dictionary (i.e. a list of valid words) and a pattern, produce the sequence of solutions to the equations matching the pattern. You can take in the input pattern in any format you want as long as it is reasonable and has a direct mapping to the format described above, and output in any reasonable format.

You can assume that the dictionary contains only strings of lowercase letters and the pattern only contains a sequence of valid equations *which has at least one solution*. You do not need to handle recursive inputs.

### Test cases

| Dictionary | Pattern | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `[one two onetwo onesix]` | `A=o..` | `one` |
| `[one two onetwo onesix]` | `A=o..;A=..e` | `one one` |
| `[one two onetwo onesix]` | `A=...` | `one; two` |
| `[one two onetwo onesix]` | `A=oneB;B=...` | `onetwo two` |
| `[one two onetwo onesix]` | `o..A=ones..` | `onesix` |
| `[one two onetwo onesix]` | `A=...;B=...;C=AB` | `one two onetwo` |

Standard loopholes are forbidden. Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest program wins.

Comment: Do we have to handle recursive inputs?

Comment: @user1502040 No.

Comment: would `A=B` be a valid pattern? If so, would that just match every word?

Comment: @gsitcia Yes, that is a valid pattern that would match every word.

Comment: 4th testcase output should be `onetwo two` instead of `onetwo one`

Comment: @gsitcia Fixed.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that we should return each word as many times as there are rules which match it (and only return dictionary words), unless the right-hand-side of the pattern is parenthesized?.

Comment: @JvdV In Qat, as in this challenge, the variables are limited to being single characters.

Comment: @user1502040 That is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I have updated the spec to remove parentheses, which should make this easier to solve.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 298 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
import re
P=product
def F(W,E):
 V={ord(i)for i in E if'@'<i<'['};E=E.split(';')
 for t in P(set().union(*[sum((l:=[i]+[x+i for x in l]for i in s),l:=[])for s in W]),repeat=len(V)):yield from P(*[[c for c in W if re.fullmatch(e.translate(dict(zip(V,t))),c+'='+c)]for e in E])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZJNj9sgEIbP4VeMtIeBDeLSSxUvUpNVes4pe7B8sGysnQoDAqJmW/W3p@B8dOsLZt5n3pkBwkd@9@7L1xAvlyn6GSibmL23CWgOPuZndl0hGnbQIfrxNGQ2mgm@8ze5FxsGR/3bx5GTmHwEAnKwB5rwG77QC7b4p9nrvUrBUubYoGBQuVy5A08mc6FOjrzjz206zZzbjW6pW7fnNS3kuZK2e5gnISvSLeVSjbx1QkYTTJ@1NY4fhdh8kLEjLBMdinE7LFbDQpfmyjRqOlk793l450bl2Ltk@2z4SEPmvyjwo8xCCDmsUeN6EEt9swzXiYsFDS16Z1AC5p@@LmX37y/RGTvGQp/LebpUcbbCrfZKoVytnqAw90Cz1UqZR/ghqU9sA8X7muDMrtn9JxbpJhe3hUif1NLK3e6a17zq7Q5vxWru1YKVfuuQoQ55b7xcb/lCJFcvD1D98OT43AeOt40sD8FKCOWwxOUv)

Brute force. Tries assigning every substring from every word to each variable.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 45 bytes

```
₄↔ƛ⁰kAfnvvV₅¹↔$vZ'ƛ÷Mƛ÷εnh=;A;A;vvh;ÞfUvṄ‛; j
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLCueKBsFxcO+KCrFxcPXbigqxXwqhTIiwi4oKE4oaUxpvigbBrQWZudnZW4oKFwrnihpQkdlonxpvDt03Gm8O3zrVuaD07QTtBO3Z2aDvDnmZVduG5hOKAmzsgaiIsIiIsIltcIm9uZVwiLCBcInR3b1wiLCBcIm9uZXR3b1wiLCBcIm9uZXNpeFwiXVxuXCJBPS4uLjtCPS4uLjtDPUFCXCIiXQ==) (times out) or [try a version with only three variables.](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLCueKBsFxcO+KCrFxcPXbigqxXwqhTIiwiM+KGlMab4oGwYEFCQ2BmbnZ2VuKChcK54oaUJHZaJ8abw7dNxpvDt861bmg9O0E7QTt2dmg7w55mVXbhuYTigJs7IGoiLCIiLCJbXCJvbmVcIiwgXCJ0d29cIiwgXCJvbmV0d29cIiwgXCJvbmVzaXhcIl1cblwiQT0uLi47Qj0uLi47Qz1BQlwiIl0=)

Tries all possible substitutions and all possible equation results so it's extremely slow.

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 776 bytes

Long, but fast.

```py
from itertools import*
U=str.isupper
E=enumerate
def f(W,p):
 q=[({},{},p)]
 for d,D,p in q:
  if[]==p:return d,D
  for i,a in E(p):
   if all(not U(j)or j in d for j in a[1]):
    H,K={},{}
    for k in product(*[d[j]if U(j)else[j]for j in a[1]]):
     for w in W:
      if all(A=='.'or A==B for A,B in zip_longest(''.join(k),w)):
       H[a[0]]=H.get(a[0],[])+[w]
       for A,B in zip_longest(a[1],k):
        if U(A):K[A]=K.get(A,[])+[B]
       Q=[(a[0],w,{})]
       for u,o,z in Q:
        if''==u and''==o:K={**K,**{i:K.get(i,[])+z[i]for i in z}};continue
        if u and o:
         if U(u[0]):
          for I,_ in E(o):Q+=[(u[1:],o[I+1:],{**z,u[0]:z.get(u[0],[])+[o[:I+1]]})]
         else:Q+=[(u[1:],o[1:],z)]
    q+=[({**d,**K},{**D,**H},p[:i]+p[i+1:])]
    break
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZLBbuMgEIbvfgpuGAdZW@1l5RUHe1spVU45VD0gVLk17pI4QDBWdl3l2bMDdtrksLdIlhkzv7/5Z8D@9b@N/v7DutOpdWaHlJfOG9P1SO2scT5LnljvXa76wVrpkgcm9bCTrvYyaWSL2vSZWlIkaM94@nGk8FgiEtQahxp6Ty1SGu0hj1TLBWO2cNIPTockbAaZonUQPaSRE4So7rpUG4@e0g0BxSbkmyiOYc3vxKRFS7pisWz8CoptUFhnmuHNpxlv@EYAMZBk10v4usKcOfHXQ9h9njfOPkrGcI4hC0EVZSWtgnBU9qUz@l32PsU43xil0y2hB3JGgjte829CsGX@Ln0aYsoFWfCDOCv@wwvW6PYLhGILJSlWvBRsFXHlxKo@WWs4gljjAPMgVyUGaugYiqwvkRgzNqBaNyEwBUwyy1Y0yz5UMZVQscTIVRyaii6Px59vRnulB3npLnKQ@cJPlgfwc9HG5OaRvkwnbkixXoDrgd8Vghr@uAgruBhp@LEYo4vhc26GFyAR4qI7hMKxXmPCe5wl@5AAYgN9rY6BfQ/REq4pL5RYWK5CzVn86mS9PVmntE/bFBstkT8YBOu89OoPznvbKZ8SytUcYobJ54A4LpnJcwxXiyS3QVFY81zeCpnf0J2WFdirbseEfiO2v53J4I2i2SQEv1hZRfbpHw)